# SheetJS/sheetjs | Using '\t' instead of ',' as delimiter for reading rows in excel file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, sheetjs

I am using https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs for getting data and parsing into javascript objects. I do not want to use the default ',' separator but use '\t' for reading the string passed into the API. Is there any way i can pass '\t' as options in ParsingOptions ?

Below is the snippet of the code,

```
const spreadsheet = '91282CBH3\t-40,000,000\t5.01\r\n91282CBH3\t50,000,000\t5.1\r\n'
import xlsx from 'xlsx';
const type = 'string';
const workbook = xlsx.read(spreadsheet, { type });
```

API from xlsx

```
/** Attempts to parse data */
export function read(data: any, opts?: ParsingOptions): WorkBook;
```

Default separator between the values is "," so the value is read from API is

```
    {
        "A": "91282CBH3**\t**-40",
        "B": 0,
        "C": 36647
    },
    {
        "A": "91282CBH3**\t**50",
        "B": 0,
        "C": 36647
    }
```

Is there way, that i can pass '\t' as delimiter instead of default "," so desired output is

```
{
        "A": "91282CBH3"
        "B": 40,000,000
        "C": 5.01
    },
    {
        "A": "91282CBH3",
        "B": 50,000,000,
        "C": 5.1
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you can specify the FS option specified here : https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/api/parse-options/

Comment: I am using version 0.17.0. and i am also using typescript. FS option is not valid in https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/blob/v0.17.0/types/index.d.ts.  ( ParsingOptions does not have FS )

Comment: You should definitely update to the latest version, but if that really isn't an option then I guess all you have to do is to replace tabs by commas before parsing (ideally making sure they aren't enclosed in quotes before replacing)

Comment: 0.17.5 is enough if you prefer, it has the FS option : https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/blob/0ddeba4fc358394438e3651910bce3b3ef29578a/types/index.d.ts#L167